# How to multiply two arrays with pointers using for loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to multiply two arrays and get the weighted average from it. How do I it using a for loop instead of the code below?

```
int main() {
    double marks[4] = { 100,89,45,88 };
    double Weightage1[4] = { 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4 };
    double WeightedAverage = 0;
    int *ptrA;
    ptrA = marks;
    double *ptrBfirst;
    ptrBfirst = Weightage1;
    
    WeightedAverage = *ptrA * (*ptrBfirst) + *(ptrA + 1) * (*(ptrBfirst + 1)) + *(ptrA + 2) * (*(ptrBfirst + 2)) + *(ptrA + 3) * (*(ptrBfirst + 3));
    cout << WeightedAverage;    
}
```

Comment: You have `double marks[4]` and then `int *ptrA; ptrA = marks`. You don't see a problem there?

Comment: Also note that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter, using array indexing syntax, is usually easier to read, understand, and write.

Comment: As for your loop, first remember that all array indexes begin with `0`. Then if you want to iterate from `0` to `3` (inclusive), what do you think such a loop would look like? What does your text-books or tutorials tell you about `for` loops?

Comment: See also [`std::inner_product`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product)

Answer (score 0):

This will be one of way to do it.

```
 int main() 
{
double marks[4] = { 100,89,45,88 };
double Weightage1[4] = { 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4 };
double WeightedAverage = 0;
double *ptrA;
double *ptrB;
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    ptrA=&marks[i];
    ptrB=&Weightage1[i];
    WeightedAverage=WeightedAverage+*ptrA**ptrB;
}
cout << WeightedAverage;    
}
```

Comment: the body of for loop can be a oneliner `WeightedAverage+=marks[i]+Weightage1[i];` using `ptrA` and `ptrB` just makes code harder to read. Just my 2 cents

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).